# How do I define a constant in C++?

Tags: c++, math, syntax

For the code:

```
#define e 2.71828183;

double p ( int x )
{
    return 1 / ( 1 + pow ( e, -1.0 * x ) );
}
```

I get:

```
math.cpp: In function ‘double p(int)’:
math.cpp:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
math.cpp:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
math.cpp:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
math.cpp:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
```

Comment: `#define e` is probably not a good idea.  How about using `exp()` instead of `pow(e, ...)`?  (This is not meant to answer your question.)

Comment: prefer "const double e = 2.71828183;" which would not have your problem

Comment: @stefaanv: Heck, put it in a namespace, too: `namespace math{ const double e = 2.71828183;}`

Comment: Note the reason for using `const double` is that the #define is a brutal tool, it will replace any other 'e' it finds in your code with that number

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a `;` at the end of your macro replacement:

```
#define e 2.71828183;
```

On preprocessing your return statement will look like:

```
return 1 / ( 1 + pow ( 2.71828183;, -1.0 * x ) );
                                 ^^
```

which results in syntax error.

To fix this remove that  `;`

Comment: Specifically, remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

The macro shouldn't have a semi-colon.

Answer (score 3):

As you question is about C++:

Here you can see problems of macro-substitution in action. Instead, use the constant:

```
double const e = 2.71828183;
```